# Java AsynchronousFileChannel - thread usage

Tags: java, asynchronous, io, nio

I understand Java's AsynchronousFileChannel to be an async api (does not block the calling thread) and can use a thread in a system thread pool.

My question is: do AsynchronousFileChannel operations have a 1:1 thread ratio?

In other words, if a loop use AsynchronousFileChannel to read 100 of files, will it use 100 threads to do that or will it use only a small number of threads (in standard NIO fashion)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`AsynchronousFileChannel` implementation used in general (and actually used e.g. on Linux) is [SimpleAsynchronousFileChannelImpl](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/nio/ch/SimpleAsynchronousFileChannelImpl.java) which basically submits `Runnables` that do blocking IO read + process result in the same thread (either fill a future or call a `CompletionHandler`) to an `ExecutorService` which either is supplied as an argument to [`AsynchronousFileChannel::open`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html#open(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.util.Set,%20java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)), or else a default system-wide one is used (which [is](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/nio/ch/ThreadPool.java#l95) an unbounded cached thread pool, but has some options that [can be configured](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousChannelGroup.html)). Some [think](http://www.remlab.net/op/nonblock.shtml) that it is the best that can be done with files since they are "always readable" or at least the OS doesn't provide any clue that they aren't.

On Windows a separate implementation is used which is called [WindowsAsynchronousFileChannelImpl](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/classes/sun/nio/ch/WindowsAsynchronousFileChannelImpl.java). It uses [I/O completion ports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx) a.k.a IOCP when run on Windows Vista/2008 and later (major version >= "6") and generally behaves more like you would expect: by default it uses 1 thread to dispatch read results (configurable by `"sun.nio.ch.internalThreadPoolSize"` system property) and a cached thread pool for processing.

So, **answering your question**: if you don't supply your own `ExecutorService` (say a fixed one) to `AsynchronousFileChannel::open`, then it will be a 1:1 relationship, so there will be 100 threads for 100 files; except for a non-ancient Windows, where by default there will be 1 thread handling I/O but if all results arrive simultaneously (unlikely but still) and you use `CompletionHandlers`, they will be called each in its own thread too.

**Edit:** I implemented reading of 100 files and ran it on Linux and Windows (openjdk8) and it 1) confirms which classes are actually used on both (for that remove `TF.class` while still specifying it in a command line and see the stacktrace), 2) sort of confirms the number of threads used: 100 on Linux, 4 on Windows if completion processing is fast (it will be the same if `CompletionHandlers` are not used), 100 on Windows if completion processing is slow. Ugly as it is, the code is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;
import java.util.*;

public class AsynchFileChannelDemo {

    public static final AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        final List<ByteBuffer> bufs = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Path p = Paths.get("some" + i + ".txt");
            final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1000000);
            AsynchronousFileChannel ch = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(p, StandardOpenOption.READ);
            ch.read(buf, 0, buf, new CompletionHandler<Integer, ByteBuffer>() {
                @Override
                public void completed(Integer result, ByteBuffer attachment) {
                  bufs.add(buf);
                  // put Thread.sleep(10000) here to make it "long"
                }

                @Override
                public void failed(Throwable exc, ByteBuffer attachment) {
                }
            });
        }
        if (args.length > 100) System.out.println(bufs); // never
        System.out.println(ai.get());
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;

public class TF implements ThreadFactory {
    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        AsynchFileChannelDemo.ai.incrementAndGet();
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        return t;
    }
}
```

Compile these, put them in a folder with 100 files named `some0.txt` to `some99.txt`, each being 1Mb in size so that reading isn't too fast, run it as

```
java -Djava.nio.channels.DefaultThreadPool.threadFactory=TF AsynchFileChannelDemo
```

The number printed is the number of times a new thread was created by the thread factory.

Comment: Not quite. [When an AsynchronousFileChannel is created without specifying a thread pool then the channel is associated with a system-dependent default thread pool that may be shared with other channels. The default thread pool is configured by the system properties defined by the AsynchronousChannelGroup class.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html)

Comment: @EJP, thank you for your feedback. I will most certainly edit my answer or remove it if it's beyond recovery, but I'd like to understand it better first. As far as I understand this thread pool is created [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/nio/ch/ThreadPool.java#l95) and as such it does use "threadFactory" and "initialSize" settings, but it still is an unbounded cached thread pool. Should I make it more clear that it's not created on a per-channel basis in my answer? Or is something else wrong with my answer?

Comment: The concept shared default thread pool seemed to point in the direction of a non 1:1 relationship: that is many files can be concurrently read using a fixed smaller number of threads, using NIO magic.  If it does not do this, then I do not know what the benefit would be of using this over standard java.ion and wrapping the execution in a thread and returning a future.

Comment: Initially I was not sure about my answer, but after the edit where I supplied the code for checking things I'm pretty confident about it: I deduced behavior from reading the source code ("theory") and confirmed it with an experiment ("practice"); also, I gave you or anybody interested links and code to check things out if one wants to. My wording might have been a bit sloppy initially, but after @EJP's comment I believe I polished it enough.