# Non-blocking reading from the file using Reactor

Tags: java, nio, project-reactor, nonblocking, nio2

Do you know if it's possible to create Flux of file lines really non-blocking way?

The best solution I've found is next:

```
Flux.using(
           () -> Files.lines(PATH),
           Flux::fromStream,
           Stream::close
 );
```

Even though it looks non-blocking but it is blocking under the hood.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-

> Read all lines from a file as a Stream. Unlike readAllLines, this
> method does not read all lines into a List, but instead populates
> lazily as the stream is consumed.
>
> The returned stream encapsulates a Reader.

Is it possible to create Flux from AsynchronousFileChannel?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you think it is blocking? Even this article describes this technique: https://www.baeldung.com/java-nio2-async-file-channel.

Comment: Hey, Artem. I don't think AsynchronousFileChannel is blocking, I tell about Files.lines(PATH) in a code example above

Comment: And why it is blocked?

Comment: Could you please provide a **minimal complete example** to illustrate the problem? In particular, what schedulers are used for the `publishOn()` and `subscribeOn()` operators?

Comment: I don’t think a scheduler should be discussed over here. I want to see first of all any arguments that stream of those lines is blocked.

Comment: I don't get how Files.lines would be non-blocking. If you use it without Reactor, it will be executed on the main thread, and opening and reading from a file is certainly blocking, there is no callback, future, etc which would indicate otherwise. Java stream doesn't make it non-blocking as it has no async support, does it?

Comment: Maybe it would be worth to check with BlockHound...

Answer (score 2):

If you have Spring Framework on classpath, then you can do the following:

```java
import org.springframework.core.codec.StringDecoder;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferUtils;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DefaultDataBufferFactory;

import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public class AsyncFileRead {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringDecoder stringDecoder = StringDecoder.textPlainOnly();

        DataBufferUtils.readAsynchronousFileChannel(() -> AsynchronousFileChannel.open(Path.of("test/sample.txt"),
                StandardOpenOption.READ), DefaultDataBufferFactory.sharedInstance, 4096)
            .transform(dataBufferFlux -> stringDecoder.decode(dataBufferFlux, null, null, null))
            .blockLast();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [RxIo](https://github.com/javasync/RxIo) library which provides a nice abstraction similar to `java.nio.file.Files` just with async/reactive support:

```java
import org.javaync.io.AsyncFiles;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import java.nio.file.Path;

public class AsyncFileRead {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flux.from(AsyncFiles.lines(Path.of("test/sample.txt")))
            .blockLast();
    }
}
```

Although, it's important to note that even these solutions are not truly non-blocking as depending on the platform (Windows, Linux) [`AsynchronousFileChannel` implementation can be blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501924/java-asynchronousfilechannel-thread-usage/39524790#39524790) under the hood but at least it delegates that task to a dedicated thread pool.